# Алгоритм для отслеживания таймаута соединения

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я сохраняю пользователей в ConcurentHashMap. Эту коллекцию использую для поиска по ID, добавляю в нее пользователя после аутентификации. Мне нужно удалить пользователя при минуте неактивности. Я могу каждую минуту в цикле идти по коллекции, но есть ли более эффективные методы?

Comment: зачем такие сложности? Напишите враппер поверх хешмапы, храните в ней не тольео юзера, но и время для удаления. При чтении проверяете, если время вышло - то прочитанные данные из мапы считаем устаревшими

Comment: хотя я бы сначала поискал, может есть уже готовый кеш в памяти для java? Задача то не специфичная, реализация кеша часто встречается

Comment: @tym32167, для того чтобы не проходить всю коллекцию мне кажется стоит сортировать по прошедшему времени

Comment: а эта коллекция сортируется по ID, то получается мне нужна другая ConcurentHashMap?

Comment: зачем что то сортровать? Смотртте. Вот у вас есть словарь. Туда помещаете юзера. Ожидание, что если вы этого юзера будете забирать меньше, чем через минуту, то он заберется, а если больше, чем через минуту, то он не найдется, так?

Comment: пишите свой класс обертку, и в методе getUserById проверяйте текущее время и время, когда туда добавили юзера в крайний раз,  и если время больше 1 минуты - то считайте "не нашли"

Comment: используйте кеш из guava https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: я так понимаю мы  не знаем какой пользователь сколько  времени бездейстовал,  так ?  Увас должен  быть  сигнал  что  пользователь  бездействует минуту. Что  явлеятся признаком  его бездейстия?